# Creating function error ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$

Tags: function, greenplum

Unable to create a SQL function - results in ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$

This is the environment: Greenplum Database 5.20.1

I am trying to create a function that will return an ordered collection of comma separated data elements as a single text.  I am trying to use the listagg function, and I discovered that it doesn't support the use of an order by while also doing a distinct.  I've distilled what I am trying to do down to what I think I need to do - which is to create a SQL function that uses the listagg function over an inline query (that is already de-duped).  So far so good.  I haven't done any Postgres code in a while, so I'm rusty.   I'm struggling with even creating SQL function properly.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;

CREATE TABLE test_Table
    (
      abk            INTEGER NOT NULL
    , effective_date DATE NOT NULL
    , end_date       DATE NOT NULL
    , anattrib          CHARACTER (70) NOT NULL
    )
    WITH (OIDS = FALSE)
    DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY;
INSERT INTO test_table(abk,effective_Date,end_date,anattrib) VALUES(1,'2019-01-01','2019-12-31','A');
INSERT INTO test_table(abk,effective_Date,end_date,anattrib) VALUES(1,'2019-06-01','9999-12-31','A');
INSERT INTO test_table(abk,effective_Date,end_date,anattrib) VALUES(1,'2019-01-01','2019-12-31','B');
INSERT INTO test_table(abk,effective_Date,end_date,anattrib) VALUES(1,'2020-01-01','9999-12-31','C');
COMMIT;
```

SQL that works and looks LIKE this:

```
SELECT string_agg(myAlias.anattrib,', ' ORDER BY myAlias.anattrib)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT anattrib FROM test_table 
  WHERE abk=1 AND '2019-06-01' BETWEEN effective_Date AND end_Date OR '2019-06-02' BETWEEN effective_Date AND end_Date) myAlias;
```

IN a FUNCTION that looks LIKE this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(myBK INT, dt1 DATE, dt2 DATE) RETURNING VARCHAR(1000) AS
$$
  SELECT string_agg( myAlias.anattrib,', ' ORDER BY myAlias.anattrib) AS anattrib_list
  FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT anattrib FROM test_table WHERE abk= $1
  AND (($2 BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_DATE AND END_DATE) OR ($3 BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_DATE AND END_DATE))) myAlias; 
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I cant even compile the SQL function - it is giving me

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE OR";
Error while executing the query. Error 7. SQLSTATE 42601
ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
LANGUAGE SQL";
Error while executing the query. Error 7. SQLSTATE 42601
```

Must be something simple. but this seems to match up with the syntax for a SQL function definition to me.

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that? Maybe that tool doesn't understand the dollar quoting

Answer (score 0):

just change RETURNING clause for RETURNS in function code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(myBK INT, dt1 DATE, dt2 DATE) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) AS
$$
 SELECT string_agg( myAlias.anattrib,', ' ORDER BY myAlias.anattrib) AS anattrib_list
  FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT anattrib FROM test_table WHERE abk= $1
  AND (($2 BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_DATE AND END_DATE) OR ($3 BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_DATE 
  AND END_DATE))) myAlias; 
$$
  LANGUAGE SQL;
```